# Is it possible to create tabGroups in Chrome via Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, vimium

As per this [article](https://www.askvg.com/tip-enable-tab-groups-feature-in-google-chrome/), I'd like to go a step further and programmatically create tabGroups in Chrome.

Is this possible via Chrome extensions?

Many thanks

Comment: Like basically any hidden feature under `chrome://flags`, this is experimental or in developement and therefore impossible to achieve through an extension.

Comment: Darn :( So there's not even an experimental API some where?

Comment: well, I see nothing in the Chrome Extension API documentation, unfortunately.

Comment: Same here :( Thanks for the confirmation